# Getting the value of a string from a parent form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the version of my product (custom personal version number) to show in a child form.

### Main Form

```
namespace My_Program
{
    public partial class mnView : Form
    {
        // Set custom version number
        public string POCVersion = "0.1.0 Beta";

        public mnView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Fills in the version number to a label on the status strip
            lblPOCVersion.Text = String.Format("Pizza Online Console Version: {0}", POCVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

### About Form

```
namespace My_Program
{
    public partial class mnAbout : Form
    {
        public mnAbout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mnView mainParent = (mnView)this.Owner;
            lblAboutCurrentVersion.Text = String.Format("Version: {0}", mainParent.POCVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

The code I have doesn't quite work. I know it's probably all wrong. A little help would be good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose you string variable as a property:

```
public string POCVersion { get{return this.POCVersion;} }
```

and call it from your child form using a parent form instance..

**OR**
you can declare it as a static variable:

```
public static string POCVersion = "0.1.0 Beta";
```

this would work with your existing form.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the version public static readonly and then use it in other classes easily:

```
public static readonly string POCVersion = "0.1.0 Beta";
```

Then you can use it like:

```
lblAboutCurrentVersion.Text = String.Format("Version: {0}", mnView.POCVersion);
```

An alternative way is to set it through the AssemblyInfo class in the Properties folder of your project and then you can access it in your code like:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

This is more standard approach as others can find the version through your exe or dll file but you only have the version in standard form x.x.x.x and cannot use expressions like "Beta" in it.